# Is there a way to make an HTML page include php, but not have a .php extension? I want to "include" my headers

Tags: php

Some pages seemingly don't have a .php extension, but they have server-side stuff in them. Or am I completely wrong with that?

Basically, I'd love to have include statements for my header and footer, without having to copy and paste changes into every HTML document, but rather update the one. Can I do this without making the page .php?

What's the best way to include those?

Comment: I don't think anyone here would say that there is anything bad about having files with a php extension by the way.

Comment: You can configure your webserver to treat any file extension as a particular type, so if you really wanted to, you can make all `.exe` files be treated as PHP scripts. It'll look like a windows box to anyone looking at the url, but it's really just a php script with a "funky" name.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Actually, yes, there is a very strong reason to avoid language-specific extensions in web pages: decoupling URLs from the language. Suppose my site is coded in php and then I decide to redo it in Rails. All of a sudden *all* of my links (and all inbound links) break as the urls change. If I set up my webserver ([tag:apache], [tag:lighttp], whatever) to serve php without extensions, then I could change the language and it would be transparent to the user, google, bing, and every other website that linked to me.

Comment: @BryanH This is easily taken care of by using mod_rewrite, just take the end of the url and switch out the extension for whatever you are using currently.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I suppose one could maintain an ever-growing .htaccess file (and dog help you if you decide to change from PHP to ColdFusion to Perl to Python, so you have to keep updating it), or you could keep it simple and just not use language-specific extensions at all. I personally prefer simple, YMMV, of course.

Comment: @BryanH If you are changing the way your website is coded that often, then more power to you, but its only one line in the httpd config file, pretty easy compared to redoing your site in a completely different language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not require a .php ending, just include it :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, make your webserver parse your HTML files as PHP scripts, then you'll be able to add `<?php include 'whatever.php';` from your .html files.

Example for Apache:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use .php?
Just create each page like this:

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';

    // your code

    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

And create a header.php for the top part of your layout and footer.php for the bottom part.
You could also look at a template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You could map the file extension html to be executed as php in a `.htaccess` file in apache

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php4 .php3 .html .htm
```

Maybe unsupported or different (1 and 1 hosted) on your server.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype